# #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am facing one problem on xampp

> 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have changed the password on the `Config.inc` file, but this doesn't resolved the issue.

Comment: Did you restart the service after changing the config file ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you, but I have resolved it.
I think you have input your default root password, we can't do it.
If you want to enter the `mariadb`, you should run `mysql_secure_installation` first to create your account for `mariadb`, and next run `mysql -uroot -p 'your password'`